# Add a comment box to a WYSIWYG in Drupal

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg, drupal-7

I would like to add a comment section to a news item on a Drupal site.

I would like to be able to do this in the WYSIWYG editor, is this possible?

If not how would I go about building a comments box option to appear when creating pages.

I know its a lot to ask, so thank you in advance for your help.

Graeme

Comment: For which Drupal version are you asking? 6 or 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a bit of research and here is a comments box. It is just a HTML box.

```
 <div id="HCB_comment_box"><a href="http://www.htmlcommentbox.com">HTML Comment Box</a> is loading comments...</div>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.htmlcommentbox.com/static/skins/simple/skin.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" id="hcb"> /*<!--*/ if(!window.hcb_user){hcb_user={};} (function(){s=document.createElement("script");s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");s.setAttribute("src", "http://www.htmlcommentbox.com/jread?page="+escape((window.hcb_user && hcb_user.PAGE)||(""+window.location)).replace("+","%2B")+"&opts=406&num=10");if (typeof s!="undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})(); /*-->*/ </script>
```

I found it here http://www.htmlcommentbox.com/

very simple, I'm sorry I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use *Comment* core module, and install a wysiwyg module like *ckeditor*, *fckeditor*, *tinymce*...